# Error while installing Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got constant problem while installing Eclipse Neon on Windows 10 (64 bit). So, I've downloaded .exe file (installer) from their page and instalation started and it was all good, but suddenly I lost internet connection. Installaton was canceled and now every time I start it again, it starts, but after few seconds it cancels and got this log:

```
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_131-b11
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.neon
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.6.0.v20161125-0947, build=2790, branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.6.0.v20161128-0928, build=2790, branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.6.0.v20161019-0656, build=2790, branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Neon))
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Offline = false
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Mirrors = true
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Resolving 23 requirements from 3 repositories to C:\Users\Bega\eclipse\java-neon\eclipse
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement epp.package.java [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201703231000
[2017-05-07 19:41:09] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2017-05-07 19:41:24] Calculating requirements and dependencies.
[2017-05-07 19:41:24] Computing prerequisite plan
[2017-05-07 19:41:28] Fetching compositeArtifacts.jar from http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest/ (444B)
[2017-05-07 19:41:29] Collecting 1 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon
[2017-05-07 19:41:29] Downloading epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2017-05-07 19:41:29] Collected 1 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon in 0.635s
[2017-05-07 19:41:29] Collecting 3 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201703231000
[2017-05-07 19:41:30] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
[2017-05-07 19:41:30] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2017-05-07 19:41:30] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2017-05-07 19:41:30] Collected 3 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201703231000 in 0.737s
[2017-05-07 19:41:31] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2017-05-07 19:41:31] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3305)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3214)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3114)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1271)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$31(SimpleVariablePage.java:1148)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1093)
 ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_Bega_eclipse_java-neon_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\Bega\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.mpc.help.ui_1.5.4.v20170201-1845.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3305)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3214)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3114)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$31(SimpleVariablePage.java:1148)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1093)
  Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3305)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3214)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3114)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$31(SimpleVariablePage.java:1148)
    ... 1 more
[2017-05-07 19:41:31]
```

I've tried all sort of things... Running it as Administrator, updating java and some option Update in installer, deleting some eclipse folders which I found in installation folder and nothing helps :/

Comment: Trying deleting `C:\Users\Bega\.p2` and the other folders, then start over

Comment: I was always deleting just .eclipse and eclipse folder, and now with deleting .p2 folder aswell with those 2 above... IT WORKS!!!! Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps something was downloaded from a mirror with a bad 
artifact. When I had strange errors like this (that look like bad 
artifacts), I generally go back in the wizard, turn off the use of 
mirrors, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the mirrors from which you are downloading.
 Basically there can be multiple FTP servers via which you can download the files,
 termed as "mirrors". 
Sometimes if the server adds up to much of load, it tries switching  your download to other server.
 During this it might take time and disconnect the download of the file.
On the official  download webpage  at right side, there is a "Direct link to file" link which chooses a reliable mirror and downloads the data automatically...

> BUT, the best way to download these files is to find them of the
>   torrents or get it from friends .. cheers..!